# How can I add videos from other users in my channel?

Tags: youtube

I want to create a channel, which will have videos uploaded by me and of other users, I found while surfing.

Also I want to convert my playlists into a channel.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I think you can do this is to make your channel's home page a list of all the videos in the playlist. Other than that there isn't any mechanism to change a playlist into its own channel